# C++ Template Class Constructor with Variable Arguments

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-functions

Is it possible to create a template function that takes a variable number of arguments, for example, in this `Vector< T, C >` class constructor:

```
template < typename T, uint C >
Vector< T, C >::Vector( T, ... )
{
    va_list arg_list;
    va_start( arg_list, C );
    for( uint i = 0; i < C; i++ ) {
        m_data[ i ] = va_arg( arg_list, T );
    }
    va_end( arg_list );
}
```

This almost works, but if someone calls `Vector< double, 3 >( 1, 1, 1 )`, only the first argument has the correct value. I suspect that the first parameter is correct because it is cast to a `double` during the function call, and that the others are interpreted as `int`s and then the bits are stuffed into a `double`. Calling `Vector< double, 3 >( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 )` gives the desired results. Is there a preferred way to do something like this?

Comment: Note that C++11's universal initializer syntax will give you this in a safe manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code looks dangerous and I think your analysis on why it isn't working is spot on, there's no way for the compiler to know that when calling:

```
Vector< double, 3 >( 1, 1, 1 )
```

the ones should be passed as doubles.

I would change the constructor to something like:

```
Vector< T, C >::Vector(const T(&data)[C])
```

instead, and have the user pass the arguments as an array. Another sort of ugly solution would be something like this:

```
template < typename T, uint C >
Vector< T, C >::Vector(const Vector<T, C - 1>& elements, T extra) {
}
```

and call it like this (with some typedefs):

```
Vector3(Vector2(Vector1(1), 1), 1);
```

Comment: Or `T(&data)[C]` and have the user pass the arguments as an array by reference. It's less flexible as it doesn't allow the use of dynamic arrays, but it can help enforce the correct number of arguments.

Comment: Also, with your second suggestion, make sure to specialize the template for `C = 0` and/or `C = 1`.

Answer (score 9):

Alas, right now there's no good way to do this. Most of the Boost packages that need to do something similar use macro tricks to define things like this:

```
template < typename T >
Vector< T >::Vector( T )
{ ... }

template < typename T, uint C >
Vector< T, C >::Vector( T t, C c1 )
{ ... }

template < typename T, uint C >
Vector< T, C >::Vector( T t, C c1, C c2 )
{ ... }

template < typename T, uint C >
Vector< T, C >::Vector( T t, C c1, C c2, C c3 )
{ ... }
```

The macros generate some set number (typically around 10) versions, and provide a mechanism to change the max number of parameters before expanding the construction.

Basically, its a real pain which is why C++0x is introducing variable-length template arguments and delegation methods that will let you do this cleanly (and safely). In the meantime you can either do it with macros, or try a C++ compiler that has support for (some of) these new experimental features. GCC is a good one for this.

Be warned though that since C++0x isn't actually out yet, things can still change and your code may not be in sync with the final version of the standard. Plus, even after the standard comes out, there'll be 5 years or so during which many compilers will only partially support the standard, so your code won't be very portable.

Comment: Check out Boost.Preprocessor if you go down the macro way. Cumulating `BOOST_PP_REPEAT` and `BOOST_PP_ENUM_TRAILING_PARAMS` should set you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks. I was in a hurry when I posted the above, so I didn't go look up what the Boost Preprocessor macros were.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want, but don't do it, because it's not typesafe. Best pass a vector of `T` or a pair of iterators containing those values.

```
template < typename T, uint C >
Vector< T, C >::Vector(int N, ... )
{
    assert(N < C && "Overflow!");
    va_list arg_list;
    va_start(arg_list, N);
    for(uint i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        m_data[i] = va_arg(arg_list, T);
    }
    va_end(arg_list);
}

Vector<int> v(3, 1, 2, 3);
```

This can be better solved, since all the elements are homogeneous typed anyway.

```
template < typename Iter, uint C >
Vector< T, C >::Vector(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
    T *data = m_data;
    while(begin != end)
      *data++ = *begin++;
}

int values[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
Vector<int> v(values, values + 3);
```

Of course, you have to make sure there is enough place in `m_data`.

Comment: If we already have `template<typename T, uint C>` and we're already making the user declare an `int values[]` array, might it not be safer (size-wise) to have the constructor be `Vector< T, C >::Vector(T (& const) [C])` ? Other than allowing slices of an array or a dynamic array, is there any reason we shouldn't allow them to just pass an array?

Comment: @Chris yeah we could do that. I found i liked to show the iterator range way though, since it's the "official" way also used by containers etc. You can also do `Vector<int> v(begin(values), end(values));` to not have to count the elements yourself, with properly defined `end` and `begin` functions (from boost.range)

Answer (score 0):

Does TypeList fit your needs?

- [Generic Programming:Typelists and Applications](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184403813)
- [Loki C++ Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loki_(C%2B%2B))
- [Tiny Template Library: implementing typelist](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/TTLTyplist.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In C++0x (really should be called C++1x), you can use template varargs to achieve what you want in a typesafe fashion (and you won't even need to specify the number of arguments!). However, in the current version of C++ (ISO C++ 1998 with 2003 amendments), there is no way to accomplish what you want. You can either hold off or do what Boost does, which is use [preprocessor macro magic](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) to repeat the definition of the constructor multiple times with different numbers of parameters up to a hard-coded, but large limit. Given that Boost.Preprocessor is kind of complicating, you could just define all of the following yourself:

```
Vector<T,C>::Vector();
Vector<T,C>::Vector(const T&);
Vector<T,C>::Vector(const T&, const T&);
// ...
```

Since the above is kind of painful to do by hand, though, you could write a script to generate it.

Comment: Everyone knows that the "x" is a hexadecimal digit ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`std::tr1::array` (which looks similar to yours) does not define a constructor, and can be initialized as an aggregate (?)

```
std::tr1::array<int, 10> arr = {{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }};
```

Also you could check out [Boost.Assignment](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html) library.

For example the constructor could be

```
template < typename T, uint C >
template < typename Range >
Vector< T, C >::Vector( const Range& r )
```

and instances created with

```
Vector<int, 4> vec(boost::assign::cref_list_of<4>(1)(3)(4)(7));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variadic , variadic means template with variable argument.[more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with variable arguments in constructors is :

- you need the cdecl calling convention (or another one that can handle varargs)
- you cant define cdecl for a constructor (in MSVS)

So the "correct" code (MS) could be :

```
template < typename T, uint C > __cdecl Vector< T, C >::Vector( T, ... )
```

but the compiler will say:

> illegal calling convention for constructor/destructor (MS C4166)