# C++ Array Initialization in Function Call or Constructor Call

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, initialization

This question is related to the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627223/c-template-class-constructor-with-variable-arguments). Is it possible to initialize an array in a function call or constructor call? For example, class foo's constructor wants an array of size 3, so I want to call foo( { 0, 0, 0 } ). I've tried this, and it does not work. I'd like to be able to initialize objects of type foo in other objects' constructor initialization lists, or initialize foo's without first creating a separate array. Is this possible?

Comment: First you talk about array initialization, then you suddently need to intialize a class object. So what is it you need to initialize: an array object or a class object?

Comment: Initializing a class is a specific case that I used as an example, and is the reason I asked the question. However, you could also have a function foo that takes an array of size 3 and want to call it as: foo( { 0, 0, 0 } ). I've changed the OP to make that more obvious.

Comment: Yes, but you are still asking "Is it possible to initialize an array without assigning it?". Well, yes, it is possible. For example, `int a[10] = { 5 }` initializes an array without assigning it, just as you asked. Yet, that doesn't look like what you really seem to be interested in.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I was thinking of a[] = { 5 } as being an assignment. However, you're right that it really isn't. I've update the post title.

Comment: "without first creating a separate array" <- do you want to prevent default construction of the actual array, or are you worried about copying the array?

Comment: I would just like to be able to keep the code concise. Instead of:
int arr[] = { 1, 1, 1 }
foo( arr );
I'd like to be able to call
foo( { 1, 1, 1 } ) or even foo( arr[] = { 1, 1, 1 } )
Also it is not possible to initialize a foo( const int( &data )[ 3 ] ) in a constructor initialization list.

Answer (score 5):

Not in the current standard. It will be possible in C++11

In gcc you can use a cast to force the creation of a temporal, but it is not standard c++ (C99):

```
typedef int array[2];
void foo( array ) {}  // Note: the actual signature is: void foo( int * )
int main() {
   foo( (array){ 1, 2 } );
}
```

Comment: This works in C99, but not in C++03 (neither in C++0x - this is a compound literal).

Comment: The code is OK with (macports) gcc up to 4.6; gcc 4.7 reports `error: taking address of temporary array`.

Comment: C++11 is the current standard, so this answer needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

If permitted by your design, you can consider wrapping the data inside a class and in default constructor initialize with 0 (or any value of your choice)