# initiate array inside function call

Tags: c++, c++11

My Question is related to the release of the c++11 standard and [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676697/c-array-initialization-in-function-call-or-constructor-call), as I wondered if it is now possible to create an array/vector inside a function call, instead of building the array/vector before and then just giving it as an parameter to the method/function.

Comment: What do you mean by "with words", is my question not understandable or somehow unpolite?

Comment: It's 100% delicious vagueness.

Comment: I am sorry for this, should have mentioned my question was related to C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>(Presuming you're talking about C++11.)</sub>

---

```
void f(int x[]) {}            // remember, same as void f(int* x) {}
int main() { f({0,1,2}); }

//  error: cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>'
//         to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'void f(int*)'
```

But:

```
void f(const int (&x)[3]) {}
int main() { f({0,1,2}); }

// <no output>
```

And:

```
void f(std::array<int, 3> x) {}
int main() { f({0,1,2}); }

// <no output>
```

And, incidentally:

```
void f(std::vector<int> x) {}
int main() { f({0,1,2}); }

// <no output>
```

So essentially **yes**, but with caveats.

Comment: Another caveat: few compilers actually support this yet. Only GCC so far as I know.

Comment: Indeed, Clang 3.0 isn't too happy with it. Still, I'm talking about the language here, not some implementation; and eventually they _will_ all support it!